# PlayORM Example compilation error

Tags: orm, cassandra, playorm

Samples run fine on my Windows 7.
However I get the following error on my Ubuntu machine:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.toDate()Ljava/util/Date;
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.spi.UniqueKeyGenerator.generateKey(UniqueKeyGenerator.java:47)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.spi.UniqueKeyGenerator.generateNewKey(UniqueKeyGenerator.java:42)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.spi.UniqueKeyGenerator.generateNewKey(UniqueKeyGenerator.java:21)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaIdField.fillInAndFetchId(MetaIdField.java:106)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaIdField.translateToColumn(MetaIdField.java:56)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle.translateToRow(MetaClassSingle.java:82)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.putImpl(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:117)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.put(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:100)
at com.example.PlayORMExample.createTestData(PlayORMExample.java:89)
at com.example.PlayORMExample.main(PlayORMExample.java:31)
```

I looked at similar questions on the "stack", but they do not seem to apply to my case.

Comment: You probably have an old version of joda-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either

1. have the wrong version of the joda-time jar OR
2. have two joda time jars one of which is the wrong version

later,
Dean (I am a committer on PlayOrm).

Comment: I checked the "build path" and only found reference to joda..2.0
Any suggestions on how to find a duplicate?

Comment: What jdk version?  What is the command you are using to run the program(along with classpath if you set it in environment variable).  Can you give us more detailed steps as well?  (NOTE: Sometimes when I restart and document my steps as well as run the steps I find my issue and end up not posting on stackoverflow).  Anyways, give us some detailed steps and I have an ubuntu instance I can try it on.

Comment: Java is 1.6.0_37 on Ubuntu and 1.7.0 on Windows. Should I try upgrading?
I am trying to run it using Eclipse (GGTS in particular).

Comment: Creating a new project and copying jars over solved the issue.
Also I discovered that the domain-class will not be usable by PlayORM unless it's part of a package.

This is def off-topic but do you think it's a good idea to use PlayORM with Grails? I know you guys support Play Framework, but I like grails and groovy better. Anything to lookout for?

Comment: It should work fine.  It is designed to work in any JVM.  PlayOrm was a bad name as I have been told many times but been too busy to change it.

Comment: The name might be "bad" but the concept/idea is terrific. I am currently investigating whether we can use PlayORM to create a Data Warehouse for our transactional data. Pure "cql"/no-joins-cassandra would not work very well for us since our data is structured/hierarchical.
Thank you Dean!

Comment: I found the reason for the initial issue:
"jruby-complete-1.6.5" library ships with "joda time 1.6.2".
Will PlayORM work with "JRuby 1.7.4"?

Comment: sure, just replace the joda-time 1.6.2 with joda time 2.0 and you should be fine.  If not, let us know and we can look at what is going on to only use the right apis that work in both but I believe 2.0 should be supporting most if not all the joda 1.6.2 methods.

Comment: oh, also in addition to previous comment, the proper/best method is to ask jruby when they will be on the 2.0 version of joda time as well...preferably we always upgrade stuff not downgrade if possible.  But let us know and we can figure something out.